# How to Convert Repeated values from rows into Column as new table

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

How to convert rows into a column in with SQL Script. Please see the sample data, In Column "Tag", there are 10 repeated values, I have to make them as a column so that I can decrease the number of rows. Can you guys please suggest me the way to do it.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shx2e.png)

Comment: what is expected output? - please provide example of it. In particular it is not clear how to treat value and qtrs columns

Comment: Please provide sample output to help.

Comment: Please see attached image 2, if we change all TAGs as rows, we should get a single row where all other columns have the same value except FORM and FP. the FORM is equal to 10-k instead of and FP is equal to FY

Comment: so 1) what is the logic for qtrs? 2) do you have fixed number of distinct tags?

Comment: 1) I have multiple values in qtrs for now, but I am separating the data as needed. So there will be a unique value in qtrs. 2) Yes, I have 10 fixed or distinct variables. those are same for other companies.

Comment: It's a bit confusing the reduction rules you applied to the rows in the second image (e.g. former vs form and qtrs). Based on the first image I think [RECORD REPEATED columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#example_schema) is what you are looking for. In this was your will have only one record, in json representation would be something like: "cik":"1084869","name":"1 800 FLOWERS COM INC","fye":"630","ddate":"20190930","tags":[{"tag":"AccountsPayableCurrent","tag":"Assests","tag":"AssetsCurrent","tag":"Liabilities","tag":"GrossProfit","tag":"NetIncomeLoss"}]}